# Getting Segmentation fault: 11ation error when starting Meteor server

Tags: meteor, segmentation-fault

When I try to start my Meteor server, I get a segmentation fault that says:

> Segmentation fault: 11ation

I am unsure as to why this is happening, and am trying to find what part of my code may be causing this to happen.  I can't post everything here from my code, but any ideas on where this may be coming from?

Comment: that `ation` is not part of the error message. it's probably random garbage which is there because of stdout/stderr buffering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out I had Meteor running in the background somehow (even after a restart).

Then look for meteor in your running processes:

```
ps -x | grep meteor
```

This gave me the following output:

```
 2080 ttys000    0:00.44 /Users/ruben/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.dr5jcc++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --smallfiles --nohttpinterface --port 3001 --dbpath /Users/ruben/Documents/projects/crewafrica/.meteor/local/db --oplogSize 8 --replSet meteor
 2141 ttys000    0:00.00 grep meteor
```

So then I do:

```
kill -s KILL 2080
meteor reset
meteor
Now everything works!
```

Credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10213345/2314341)

Comment: FYI: No need for `meteor reset` for me, Keep in mind that this clears out all your mongodb! it's a huge price if you are in testing phase.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was fixed by removing blank lines in `.meteor/packages` list, then running `meteor update`.

Answer (score 1):

If the existing solutions didn't work then try this one.

open the terminal and get superuser permission.

MAC -- navigate to the project folder and type sudo su

WINDOWS -- go to a project folder press shift and right click and open command prompt here.

Now type meteor