# Unexpected mongo exit code 100 with Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to follow this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15752736/4167140

But the path `/usr/local/meteor` does not exist on my OSX.  I ran a single Meteor app on my machine for months and it worked fine, but now that I have multiple meteor apps on my mount, I keep on getting...

> Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.

...when I go to run any of the apps locally (aside from the first one I created).

Did I install Meteor incorrectly?  I curl'd it down and I have the executable in `/usr/local/bin/meteor`, but I need to be able to access `/usr/local/meteor` in order to get verbose logging when I run `mongod` inside of the directory.

This happens even on Meteor applications that dont have any collections (just static content).

I have never run into this issue with any of the Meteor + MongoDB applications that I run on my Ubuntu boxes.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?  There's a bug on github for it...

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2772

Hey, I don't really have enough to go on for a good answer.  But, the .lock file isn't the database.  It's a file mongodb writes to prevent itself from starting *again* on your database.  That would get messy.  If mongodb crashed, and didn't delete the .lock it wouldn't start again without manual intervention.

Comment: deleting the database is not solution to this problem.

Comment: Hey, I don't really have enough to go on for a good answer.  But, the .lock file isn't the database.  It's a file mongodb writes to prevent itself from starting *again* on your database.  That would get messy.  If mongodb crashed, and didn't delete the .lock it wouldn't start again without manual intervention.

Comment: in any case, I have attempted this solution but and sometimes it works, but  the problem persists.

Comment: I would guess then that the real problem is MongoDB keeps crashing.  Are you out of disk space?  Out of memory?  Take a look in the mongodb logs...

Comment: I am not out of disc space.  which logs are you referring to?  I have already run `mongod` in `./meteor/local/db` and I dont get anything out of the ordinary.  it does say `connections: 0` though

Answer (score 0):

Before of to check the installation of Meteor, you could see in your app directory if there is any mongodb.lock, in that case just delete it with `rm .meteor/local/db/mongodb.lock` (that path is on my linux, maybe it can change a bit, so please check it)

Comment: deleting mongodb.lock is not a solution to this problem.  it is a bandaid.

Comment: Also are you sure you stopped the mongod before of to delete the mongodb.lock?