# Can't run meteor on windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, mongodb, meteor

My issue is that i can't run the command : `meteor`. Whenever I try using this command inside a newly created project or from an existing project that I created from my other computer, the command just exits and writes :

```
[[[[[ C:\Users\XYZ\simple-todos ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Can't start Mongo server.
MongoDB had an unspecified uncaught exception.
This can be caused by MongoDB being unable to write to a local database.
Check that you have permissions to write to .meteor/local. MongoDB does
not support filesystems like NFS that do not allow file locking.
```

I'm on windows 10. On an other desktop under windows 8, I never had this problem. I also use the latest version of meteor (1.4.3.2).

I tried many things like `meteor update`, `npm update`and so on but nothing worked. I don't have any file inside `.meteor/local/db`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting your Meteor instance in a Read-only (from the Meteor-Mongo user Point of View) or non supported type of partition (NFS).

Change root directory of your project (your "home") and it should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks it worked ! Apparently the only place where I can run a Meteor app is in a folder at the root of C:/.

Comment: I don't think so :) but you at least need to be able to write in the folder

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that [Mongo doesn't want to start without properly set locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15752736) ? Try to run `export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"` command before `meteor` command.